# Joomla RTL support for module

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5, right-to-left, joomla-module

I am trying to support RTL for my Joomla module. I was wondering if there is any Joomla class that can determine if RTL language is currently in use such as:

```
$lang = JFactory::getLanguage();
if ($lang->isRTL()) {
   //do something here
}
```

I have tested the code above which I found in the Official Joomla Forums, but it does not seem to work.

In the Beez20 template I saw the following code:

```
if ($this->direction == 'rtl') {

}
```

but assumed this a template based statement.

So my question is, is there any way I can detect if the language that the website is being viewed in is an RTL language?

Comment: the first code snippet worked. I simply got my `if` statements a little muddled up

Comment: Add it as the answer and mark it solved then!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first code snippet used in my answer works as shown below as well:

```
$lang = JFactory::getLanguage();
if ($lang->isRTL()) {
   //do something here
}
```

Only reason being it didn't work, was because I had another 2 if statements that were the wrong way round to this one.